# jQuery - Show/Hide Conundrum

Tags: jquery, show-hide

So I am building a Glossary page, you know, you click A-Z and it shows the words assocated with that letter below.

The problem is, now that I have all the "word blocks" hiding from the get-go (`$(".words").hide();`) none of them are being shown when I click the letters.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="letterBar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="letter" id="selector-A">
        <span>A</span>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="letter" id="selector-B">
        <span>B</span>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="letter" id="selector-C">
        <span>C</span>
    </a>
   .... and so on to Z
</div>
```

And the HTML for the words to be shown below. (words removed, just for structure purposes.)

```
<div id="viewGlossary">
    <div class="words" id="glossary-A">
    </div>
    <div class="words" id="glossary-B">
    </div>
    <div class="words" id="glossary-C">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my show/hide javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".words").hide();

    $(".letter").click(function(){
        var whichLetter = $(this).children("span").text();
        $(".words").fadeOut(200, function(){
            $(selectedGloss).fadeIn();
        });
        var selectedGloss = "#glossary-" + whichLetter;
        console.log(selectedGloss);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".words").hide();

    $(".letter").on('click', function(){
        var sel = $('#glossary-' + this.id.replace('selector-','') );

        $(".words").fadeOut(200, function(){
            sel.delay(200).fadeIn(200);
        });
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yeANF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try declaring the selectedGloss to be the first line within the  ".letter" click function.

Comment: Also, try putting a breakpoint inside the .letter click. Then you should be able to observe if any of the selectors/variables are undefined. Go from there.